# Creating tags and branches for a subversion repository after the repository has already been created

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm a newbie, so please be gentle.

We use subversion at my work to track our changes to rather large software projects that we receive from another entity.  However, because we never branch our software we have not followed the traditional concept of trunk/tags/branches hierarchy for our repository.  We simply create the repository using:

```
svnadmin create /data/svn/projectName
```

on the server, then 
    svn import src svn://svnserver/projectName -m "First Import"
on the client then we check out to a working directory.

However, now I would like to add tagging to our various software releases.  I have tried to restructure the repository following several links like:

http://grand-prismatic.blogspot.com/2013/08/add-trunk-tags-branches-directory.html

but maybe I don't understand what they are doing.  I thought that the trunk/branches/tags directories were part of the repository structure, but not part of the physical structure of the source code.  When I follow the link above, I wind up with tags/branches/trunk directories in my working copy, which I do not want.

Do I misunderstand the function of tags and branches?  Is there a way to add a tags directory to the repository without it having to appear in my working copy?

Comment: No, you checked out the 'root' of the project, there is no way to 'rewrite' that. What you can do is `switch` your working copy to `/trunk` (or your desired branche/tag). Tags & branches are directories in svn (contrary to some other vcs's).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check out the tags directory. Typically you will work with the content under trunk or the content under one of your branches. You can check out any part of the repository (trunk say, or one directory within trunk) to your working directory.

The contents of the tags directory will be the "labelled" or epoch versions of trunk or any branch. For example when a release is tested and ready a copy from trunk or a branch to the tags directory which will hold all the correct versions at the time of the release.

The directory names trunk, tags, branch are not enforced. You could call them whatever you wish. Idiomatically it's best to use these names as when you refer to svn commands the explanations will chime with your svn setup. If you only ever have one code stream (trunk) and never deviate to branch the code for projects, and you never need to make tags of a particular version, you could simply use one directory to hold all your versions in the SVN repository.

This command will check-out branch1 to the directory you specify (/branch1-srcdir):

```
svn co SVN-URL/branch1  /branch1-srcdir
```

or similarly for trunk:

```
svn co SVN-URL/trunk /trunk-srcdir
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how Subversion works. You use branches by checking them out or switching to them.

```
REPO_ROOT
├── branches
│   ├── feature1
│   └── feature2
├── tags
└── trunk
```

You don't want to checkout the REPO_ROOT. You want to checkout subdirectories, such as `/trunk`, or `/branches/feature1`. You can switch to a different branch like this:

```
svn switch ^/branches/feature2
```

You can create a new branch from the trunk like this:

```
svn cp ^/trunk ^/branches/newfeature
```

This doesn't mean that files are duplicated inside the repository. The new branch is sort of like a symbolic link in the filesystem in the sense that it doesn't duplicate anything, but Subversion has its own way to make this efficient.

If you checkout an entire REPO_ROOT, the internal repository structure will be recreated on your computer as a regular filesystem, which would be huge. People don't use Subversion this way. You always checkout the branches you want to work with.

**UPDATE**

When you create a repo it will have a physical directory structure like this:

```
$ svnadmin create myrepo
$ tree myrepo/ -L 1
myrepo/
├── conf/
├── db/
├── format
├── hooks/
├── locks/
└── README.txt
```

This has nothing to do with the structure that is under version control, the `/trunk`, `/branches`, `/tags` layout. The new repository is created completely blank:

```
# this outputs nothing
svn ls file://$PWD/myrepo
```

The `/trunk`, `/branches`, `/tags` layout is just a convention. If you decide to use it, you have to create the layout yourself, for example like this:

```
$ svn checkout file://$PWD/myrepo mycheckout
Checked out revision 0.
$ cd mycheckout/
$ mkdir -v trunk branches tags
mkdir: created directory `trunk'
mkdir: created directory `branches'
mkdir: created directory `tags'
$ svn add *
A         branches
A         tags
A         trunk
$ svn commit -m 'created standard layout'
Adding         branches
Adding         tags
Adding         trunk

Committed revision 1.
```

After this I would just trash the `mycheckout` directory, and then checkout the `/trunk` and add the project files in another commit.

This layout is not visible in the physical directory of `myrepo`. It's only visible when you browse the repo content with a repo browser, or with `svn ls URL` commands.

You can read more about the recommended repository layout here:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.layout

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am beginning to understand what is going on, however, I am still confused on what seems to be such a trivial concept that it is just assumed that everyone understands it.
If I use svnadmin create /usr/tmp/svn/repos I get a subversion repository called repos in /usr/tmp/svn. Now I am assuming that repos corresponds to the REPO_ROOT in your post.  This directory now contains the conf, dbs, etc stuf that is in a typical repository.  How do I then restructure the repository so that it under repos is trunk/tags/branches and that the conf, dbs, etc is under trunk?

Comment: @user3170250 I added more explanations to my post.